# \includegraphics caused missing number, treated as zero error

Tags: errors

I was trying to include an image in my file but this error came up:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   o
l.207               \includegraphics{rate\_of\_return}
```

I've looked everywhere and tried a lot of things, but the problem remains unresolved.

This is my code:

```
% ... some stuff

\item[c)] \hfill \\
    In the graph below, the full line is for 7\%, the long-short dashed
    line is for 6\%, and the regular dashed line is for 5\%.
        \includegraphics{rate\_of\_return}

% ... some stuff
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Did you try with `\includegraphics{rate_of_return}`?

Comment: Ignasi - that worked. I didn't know that you didn't need to escape the underscores for \includegraphics.

Comment: mafp - Thank you for editing my post. Next time I'll definitely do that.

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer (or accept an existing answer) instead of editing your question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to escape underscores in file names. So you should use `\includegraphics{rate_of_return}`. Same happens with other file commands like `\input`, `\include` or `\includeonly`.

You need to escape underscores when you want to type `_` in the middle of your text.